# How do I show radio wave characteristics and direction in 4 dimensions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euclidean-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

I want to show a radio wave changing directions from one start point (0,0,0) as it relates to time in a Euclidean space.

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna somewhere related to your topic?

Comment: Yes, the radio wave shown being received by the antenna is what I want to show in a spherical coordinate system at various directions around point (0,0,0)